# How to add or remove a value inside a table cell on selection / de-selection of checkbox of that row, trying to submit the value via Jquery?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Here is the table:

```
<%= form_tag '', :id => "costs" do %>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="service_cost">
    <% @services.each do |service|  %>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag :open_service,  {}, false, :class => 'checkable' %></td>  
            <td><%= service.phone %></td>
            <td><%= service.internet %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><%= service.house_keeping  %> </td>
            <td>0.0 </td>
            <td><%= service.laundry %></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag "service_cost", service.total, :class => "input-small" %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

when the form gets submitted, the javascript gets into action:

```
$("#costs").submit(function(){
  formData=$("#costs").serializeArray();
  processFormData(formData)
  return false;
});
```

This ensures form submission on selecting the checkbox:

```
$('.checkable').live('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

But, what I am looking for is adding or removing a cell value based on checkbox selection/de-selection and submitting it, kindly suggest a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if hide will work on a td if the table has multiple rows but if it does something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="data">data</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkable" value="data"></td>
    </tr>
</table

$('.checkable').live('change', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr.data').hide();
      $(this).parents('form:first').submit();

});
```

Comment: RE: How do I add var row into my serializeArray() - not sure exaclty how this works, I usually use .serialize(), and it will submit all form data for you via ajax. Just check the value of the checkbox, if it has one it was ticked

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= check_box_tag :check %>
<%= form_tag '', :id => "costs" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag, :detbycb, :size=>20 %>
<% end %>

$('#check').on('change', function() {
   if ( $('#check').is(':checked') )
      $('#detbycb').val('I Am Checked');
   else
      $('#detbycb').val('I AM NOT checked');
}

OR

$('#check').on('change', function() {
   if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
      $('#detbycb').val('I Am Checked');
   else
      $('#detbycb').val('I AM NOT checked');
}

The first better illustrates,  the second is the real way, faster execution
```